# Prolog - Working with a list of lists and an element inside one of the sublists

Tags: prolog, logic, nested-lists, list-manipulation

I know some questions here are similar to this one, but I'm inexperienced and I don't know how to use them and convert the solutions to my problem ;/

I have a list with lists inside, like this one:

`[ [5],[4,7],[1,2,7],[2,6,7],[2,4,6,7],[2,4,7],[9,8],[3],[1] ]`

and I need to know the index of, e.g., the number 3. The number I need to know will only appear on the list of lists once, that's a previous condition to call the function. The index I need is, for the number 3, the index 9 (starts at 1). I had this draft of a function:

```
given_elem_finds_pos(ListOfLists, Element, Pos):-
    nth1(Pos, ListOfLists, [Element|_]).
```

But it only returns the Pos if the Element is the head of a sublist. I need to know how to get to the index of e.g. the number 8.

Then I did this one:

```
given_elem_finds_pos( [[H|T]| R], Element, Ind):-
member(Element, [H|T]),
Ind1 is Ind + 1,
given_elem_finds_pos(R, Element, Ind1).
```

But again, not successful.. Can anyone help? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second approach is going into the right direction. Just think what you want to describe: If `Element` is an element of `[H|T]` you want to stop, hence, no need to have a recursive call here. Furthermore, you would like to return the current index, thus you need an extra argument (one for the counter and one for the final index). The recursive clause is needed for the case that `Element` is not an element of the list. Here is the clause for the case that it is an element

```
 given_elem_finds_pos( [List| R], Element, Solution,Solution):-
        member(Element, List).
```

As you have to add the extra argument you need an additional predicate that calls your extended predicate:

```
given_elem_finds_pos(ListOfLists, Element, Ind):-
        given_elem_finds_pos(ListOfLists, Element,0, Solution).
```

Now you only have to write one more clauses for `given_elem_finds_pos/4`, a recursive one for the "it's not an element" case. Ask, if you have trouble writing this clause.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! I'm working on the other clause and trying to figure out what you did, so I can't say it's all done, but tell me something: in the last iteration, or last time given_elem_finds_pos/4 is called, Prolog ends up with an Index that kept being increased by one, right? Or you don't do that on yours? Because if you do, isn't that final value the same as Solution?

Comment: Yes you are right, the counter is increasing and if the searched sublist is found the counter equals the index. That is why you need the extra argument. The stop clause in my code, beginning with `given_elem_finds_pos( [List| R], Element, Solution,Solution):-`, instantiates the solution index with the current counter.